# find specific links that contain a word and add to array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to search a page for links that contain the word playgame. If they found then I add them to an array. After that Select a random value from the array and use `window.location`. My problem is that it says my `indexof` is undefined. I not sure exactly that what means as I am still learning to use this feature of javascript.

example of link

```
<a href="playgame.aspx?gid=22693&amp;tag=ddab47a0b9ba5cb4"><img src="http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/running-lion-2/_thumb_100x100.jpg"></a>
```

javascript

```
var gameLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
if (gameLinks.href.indexOf("playgame") != -1) {
    var links = [];
    links.push(gameLinks.href);
    var randomHref = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
    window.location = randomHref;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that it says my indexof is undefined

Not `indexOf`, the thing you're calling it on. `gameLinks` is a `NodeList`, it doesn't have an `href` property. You need to loop through the contents of the list to look at the individual element's `href` property. E.g.:

```
var index, href, links, randomHref, gameLinks;
gameLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
// Loop through the links
links = [];
for (index = 0; index < gameLinks.length; ++index) {
    // Get this specific link's href
    href = gameLinks[index].href;
    if (href.indexOf("playgame") != -1) {
        links.push(href);
    }
}
randomHref = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
window.location = randomHref;
```

More to explore:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

Comment: thank and yes i forgot to add the `var` for those variables. I updated my post. I am testing your code but the array only populates with the word undefined. does that mean the "playgame" string is not being found?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 - In T.J.'s code, `links.push(gameLinks.href);` should be `links.push(href);`.  I've edited T.J.'s code to correct.

Comment: thank you both so much for your time and help. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Mr.1.0: No worries. FWIW, putting `var` all over your code is not best practice, because it's misleading. `var` should be at the top of the function (or the top of the global scope, but really it's best not to have global variables). Here's why: *[Poor misunderstood `var`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)*.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I like the way you code. Could you recommend some resources for me to learn more about JavaScript?

Comment: @Mr.1.0: The book *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by Flanagan is pretty good. Read [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com) but don't take his word as gospel (he has a tendency to express his opinions as facts), make up your own mind about the points he raises. (You might wait to read Crockford until you've got the basics down.) [I blog about JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript) a bit. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is pretty good for reference, but beware there is some sub-standard code there.