# find href based on word

Tags: javascript

I have a set of links I want to find on a page, but only if the href contains the word "PlaySounds" I tried the following code but i get undefined.

```
    http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=546444456
    http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=347457458
    http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=275656573
    http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=976645654

    hrefs = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function(node) { 
            return node.href.indexOf("PlaySounds") === 0;
        }).map(function(node) {
            return node.href;
        });

randomHref = hrefs[Math.floor(Math.random() * hrefs.length)];

    console.log(randomHref );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [find specific links that contain a word and add to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409077/find-specific-links-that-contain-a-word-and-add-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.indexOf returns the starting position of the substring you are searching for or -1 if it is not found.

try changing

```
node.href.indexOf("PlaySounds") === 0;
```

with

```
node.href.indexOf("PlaySounds") >= 0;
```

Edit: Tested it with this function

```
function randomHref() {
    hrefs = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function(node) { 
        return node.href.indexOf("PlaySounds") >= 0;
    }).map(function(node) {
        return node.href;
    });
    return hrefs[Math.floor(Math.random() * hrefs.length)];
}
```

on these links:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=2">asd</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=4">asd</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=1">asd</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/uno/PlaySounds.aspx?Id=3">asd</a>
```

Comment: @Mr.1.0: Works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/XFdtG/. Make sure you execute the code when the links are available, not beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Why the === 0

```
hrefs = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function(node) { 
        return node.href.indexOf("PlaySounds") !== -1;
    }).map(function(node) {
        return node.href;
    });

randomHref = hrefs[Math.floor(Math.random() * hrefs.length)];

console.log(randomHref );
```